# Finding the complement of a set by negating logical statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, computational-complexity

As part of an exercise I've been given the assignment to find the complement of the following statement:

L = {P⊆{0,1}*: P is a legal encoding of a C program, and P terminates on all but a finite set of inputs}

The way I approached the question is as follows,
X = P is a legal encoding of a C program
Y = P terminates on all but a finite set of inputs
Thus the statement I have to find the complement for is X AND Y which means
NOT(X AND Y) = NOT(X) OR NOT(Y)
now this is the part where I'm hitting a wall, 
NOT(X) = P is **not** a legal encoding of a C program
NOT(Y) = ???

I honestly am not sure as to how to negate that statement, I've been thinking about several statements as follow:
1. there exists a non finite set of inputs which P does not terminate on
2. there exists a finite set of inputs which P does terminate on
3. 1 OR 2   (logical OR)
4. something else?

Will appreciate any assistance or suggestion!

Comment: What does * mean in this context?

Comment: {0,1}* means all the possible binary strings of length 0 or more, I.E. {ε,0,1,00,01,10,11,000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111,0000....}

Comment: It seems to me that the correct choice for NOT(Y) is "P does **not** terminate on an infinite set of inputs".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thing is, the negation of the fact it terminates for all should be that there is at least one that it does not terminate on, or am I wrong with my assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I_P$ be the set of inputs for $P$. I can rephrase $Y$ as: There exists a finite set $N\subset I_P$ such that $P$ does not terminate on $N$, and such that $P$ terminates on $T=I_P-N$ (the set difference, the set of inputs not in $N$).

The negation $\text{NOT}(Y)$ of this statement is: There does *not* exist a finite set ... and so on as above, but if there does not exist such a finite set, then the set of inputs for which $P$ does not terminate, must be infinite.

So $\text{NOT}(Y)$ ends up as: There exists an infinite set $N\subset I_P$ such that $P$ does not terminate on $N$, and such that $P$ terminates on $T=I_P-N$ (the set difference, the set of inputs not in $N$).

Or in short (and informally): $P$ doesn't terminate for an infinite number of inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this is what I thought was the right direction although I couldnt break it down like you did!